# Visual Studio: Place cursor mid screen

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2015 or 2017), are there shortcuts for these actions? I've been Googling, unsuccessfully:

- To place the cursor in the vertical middle of the screen, at beginning of the line.
- To place the cursor at the middle of a line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: For better document navigation, while editing text.

Comment: Maybe you see something I don't, but I still can't tell how it's useful _in terms of navigation_ to have the cursor in the center of a line or in the middle of the screen, thus, I don't think there are shortcuts for these AFAIK. I believe that `Ctrl`+Arrows, `Home`, and `End` do provide good/easy document navigation.

Comment: People that have used editors like Vim and Emacs will understand.

Comment: I stand corrected.